# what should be done for upgrading JQuery Mobile?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

i used to using 1.0.1 and i am trying to update to 1.3.0.

in the head section of the html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

i think i simply change the value here and download the files should be fine.

however, after refresh the page, i found that the page is simply displaying without css.

is there any things need to do for the upgrade?

my original ones

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css" />
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to change **jQuery** version. Each **jQuery Mobile** version has a min/max **jQuery** requirement.

If you are using **jQuery Mobile** version 1.3 I would advise using **jQuery** version 1.9.1. and dont go any higher then that or lower then 1.8.3.